# How to handle token in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android application and i am implementing push notifications functionality on it.

I keep on my server all the users tokens , so that i can send them a notification when needed.

***However*** , i need some help on how(or more precisely when) to send the token from the application to my server to save it.

At the moment , in the first time the applications launches , the application asks for a token and then sends the token along with the UDID to my server. However because of my implementation the 1st time the application launches the token is not yet retrieved and so an empty string is sent to my server! Of course the 2nd time and on the token is sent normally. (i register the udid and token to my server every time the application launches)

The code looks something like this :

```
    //registering for push
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
      Log.i("****************","I just Registered!!");
    } else {
      Log.i("****************","Already registered");
    }

    final String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    String jsonString = "{\"deviceUUID\":\"" + android_id + "\",\"os\":\"android\", \"pushToken\":\"" + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this) + "\"}";

 . . . Sending the jsonString to my server . . .
```

As you see the first time the `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)` is null as the call to retrieve a new token is *asychronous* and happens after i send the data to my server.

The next time the application launches the token will be send normally but it needs to get fixed.

One idea is to always register for token :

```
    //registering for push
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
```

and inside the `protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId)` function of the **GCMIntentService** class send the token to my server. That way the token will always be retrieved before i send it and be sure is never null the 1st time.

Actually this is exactly how things are done in an iOS app. Usually you send the token to your server inside the function that retrieves it , so that you are sure its going to actually be there before you try to send it.

Is this approach correct? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GCM library you should register the token on your server in function

```
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
```

If you are not using library then you will have do something like this in your GCMIntentService

```
@Override
public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            handleRegistration(intent);
        } else if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
            handleMessage(intent);
        }
    } finally {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            sWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

where `handleRegistration()` is the function which sends token to server.

When you send token to your server and if gets registered successfully you can use

```
GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
```

Then you can know whether the token is registered with your server or not by using

```
GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context);
```

Comment: Yes thats what i understood too that the token should be sent through the onRegistered function. However i have a small question. I want to send the token every time my application launches. So the line : if (regId.equals(""))  , i think doesnt make a lot of sense as this will be null only the first time. I want my device to require every time a new token and register it to my server. So i should always run :   GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);  on launch. Is this correct? The code i used above was from google , but i dont understand why they require token only 1time. If it changes ?

Answer (score 0):

While you are in the `GCMIntentService` you are already on a separate thread from the UI thread. I'll say it's a good point to approach your server.

One thing you should think of is how to make it fail safe. what happens when the call from the GCM returned the registration key but your api call to your server failed. I would recommend in that case to check at least in the next application launch that you don't have any registration id waiting to be sent to server, and if so - send them OR just re-register to GCM and let the procedure reoccur.

Comment: I dont understand your 2nd paragraph. The call to my server is a simple http request. It happens when the app launches. If it fails it fails. The next time the app will launch there will be a new http request. So what could go wrong there?